# Can not get cookies in ReactJS with ViteJs

Tags: reactjs, cookies, vite

I have a get request to Nest JS backend. Making the request using `CRA` then the cookies are set in my browser, but trying to make the request using React Js that was generated using ViteJs, then i don't get any cookies in my browser. 
 Question: Why i can not get cookies using Vite and React but with CRA works? Do the cookies work only with localhost as CRA works, because VITE url is something like `http://127.0.0.1:5173/` but not localhost as in CRA?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the DNS default result order to verbatim will replace the ip address with localhost which should allow your cookies to be set.

When setting cookies the url you are sending the request from and the cross-origin url need to be the same. This happens with vite due to it having a different start address, but does not happen with CRA.

This is my code for my vite config file:

```
    import { defineConfig} from "vite";
    import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
    import dns from 'dns'

    dns.setDefaultResultOrder('verbatim')

    // https://vitejs.dev/config/
    export default defineConfig({
        plugins: [react()],
        server: {
            host: "localhost",
            port: "3002",
        },
    });
```